# ui-router: Is there a way to have variables in the beginning of the url?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to have a variable in my route like this:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('edit', {
        url: ':organization/edit',
        templateUrl: 'partials/edit.html',
        controller: 'editController',
        controllerAs: 'editController'
    })
```

And have that working at the same time as using

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('index');
```

Is that possible? Because what I find is that the otherwise-rule kicks in when I try to go to

```
myOrganization/edit
```

and then I'm redirected to index. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible, as shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zvneCCEIXzUde4fUhdqQ?p=preview). The trick is to define index as the first state *(well, not as a first, but before the edit)*:

```
  .state('index',{
    url:'/index',
    template:'<div>index</div>',
  })
  .state('edit', {
    url: '/:organization/edit', 
    ...
  })
```

The `ui-router` will evaluate url state by state, as they where defined. The first match will decide. So if the index, in this case is found, index state is selected...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zvneCCEIXzUde4fUhdqQ?p=preview)

*My (private) suggestion would be: do not count on order. Try to define states to be really simply identified. Even more, my experience is, that if users do use url, they copy/paste... so, it could be a bit more talkative...*

Comment: Great to see that... If you can, please, also try to think about my suggestion... just suggestion ;)